# Blackberry - How to center the datepicker popup for DateField

Tags: blackberry, datepicker

I have `DateField` in center of my screen

[image]

And when I touch it I see:

[image]

But I want to see:

[image]

My question is:

How can I center the datepicker popup for `DateField`?

Blackberry OS 6

**Update:**

```
public class MyMainScreen extends MainScreen
{
    protected DateField dateField_ = null;
    protected VerticalFieldManager container_ = null;

    public MyMainScreen()
    {
        super();
        container_ = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL
            | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
        {
            protected void sublayout(int width, int height)
            {
                super.sublayout(width, height);

                layoutChild(dateField_ , 100, 40);
                setPositionChild(dateField_ , (width - 100) / 2, 50);

                setVirtualExtent(width, 50);
            }
        };

        add(container_);
        dateField_ = new DateField("", new Date(), new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"), Field.FIELD_HCENTER |
                DrawStyle.HCENTER | Field.FOCUSABLE);

        container_.add(dateField_);
        add(container_);
    }
}
```

Comment: The pictures are good, but please also show the **code** you're using, that produces this problem.  (we don't need to see any code other than the Screen class you use for this, and how you add a DateField to it)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there's a few problems:

1. the `DateField` won't center the field just because you pass `Field.FIELD_HCENTER | DrawStyle.HCENTER` into the constructor.  I don't think `DateField` even recognizes those flags.
2. A `VerticalFieldManager` is a special `Manager` that's designed to lay out its children vertically from top-to-bottom in the order you `add()` them.  If you're **not** going to lay out the fields that way, then I don't know that you should extend `VerticalFieldManager`.  Just extend `Manager` directly, if you want to implement `sublayout()`.  Also, calling `super.sublayout()` in your implementation might cause issues.
3. You are hardcoding the height/width of your `DateField`.  I'm not sure it allows that.
4. Your code didn't actually compile for me, as the `DateField` constructor takes a `long` date, not a `Date`.  That doesn't have anything to do with centering though.

So, I'd recommend something like this:

```java
  super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

  dateField_ = new DateField("", (new Date()).getTime(), new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"), Field.FOCUSABLE);

  container_ = new Manager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR) {
     public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return Display.getHeight();
     }
     public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Display.getWidth();
     }
     protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {            
        int h = Math.min(height, Display.getHeight());
        setExtent(width, h);
        // only needed if there's actually more content than fits in the visible area
        //setVirtualExtent(width, h + ?);

        int dfWidth = dateField_.getPreferredWidth();
        int dfHeight = dateField_.getPreferredHeight();
        layoutChild(dateField_, dfWidth, dfHeight);
        setPositionChild(dateField_, (width - dfWidth) / 2, (h - dfHeight) / 2);
     }                                      
  };

  container_.add(dateField_);      
  add(container_);
```

P.S.  I wasn't sure if you wanted scrolling or not.  With only a `DateField`, there's no reason to scroll.  But, I know your real `Screen` probably has more content, so you may need to `setVirtualExtent()`, which I've commented out.

Comment: I did not properly moved your code into my application. Now it's work perfect. Thank you very much you would always help me!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me also:

```
package com.my.package;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import net.rim.device.api.i18n.SimpleDateFormat;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.DateField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.picker.DateTimePicker;

public class MyDateManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
    protected DateField dateField_ = null;
    protected DateTimePicker dateTimePicker_ = null;
    protected SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_ = null;

    public MyDateManager() {
        super(Manager.FIELD_HCENTER | Manager.FIELD_VCENTER);
        dateFormat_ = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        dateField_ = new DateField("", new Date().getTime(), dateFormat_,
                Field.FIELD_HCENTER | DrawStyle.HCENTER | Field.FOCUSABLE) {
            protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent paramTouchEvent) {
                if (paramTouchEvent.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK) {
                    dateField_.setEnabled(false);
                    showDatePicker();
                }
                return super.touchEvent(paramTouchEvent);
            }

            protected boolean trackwheelClick(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
                dateField_.setEnabled(false);
                showDatePicker();

                return super.trackwheelClick(paramInt1, paramInt2);
            }
        };
        this.add(dateField_);
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        layoutChild(dateField_, width, height);
        setPositionChild(dateField_, (width - dateField_.getWidth()) / 2,
                (height - dateField_.getHeight()) / 2);
        int h = dateField_.getHeight();
        if (h <= 0)
            h = height;
        setExtent(width, h);
    }

    protected void showDatePicker() {
        if (dateTimePicker_ == null) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            // HACK
            String dateFormat = dateFormat_.toPattern().indexOf("H", 0) == -1 ? dateFormat_
                    .toPattern() : null;
            String timeFormat = dateFormat_.toPattern().indexOf("H", 0) != -1 ? dateFormat_
                    .toPattern() : null;

            dateTimePicker_ = DateTimePicker.createInstance(cal, dateFormat,
                    timeFormat);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (dateTimePicker_.doModal()) {
                        dateField_.setDate(dateTimePicker_.getDateTime()
                                .getTime());
                    }

                    dateField_.setEnabled(true);
                    dateField_.setFocus();
                    dateTimePicker_ = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```